# Toggle rows created using Repeater Control ASP.NET

Tags: asp.net, jquery

I am creating a list of data using Repeater Control. Some of the rows might have other rows that should be toggled using the main row's clickable image.

Here, is the HTML part

```
<table cellpadding="2" cellspacing="0" width="100%">
                <asp:Repeater ID="repeatLockers" runat="Server">
                    <HeaderTemplate>
                        <tr>
            <td>&nbsp;</td>
                            <td>A</td>
                        </tr>
                    </HeaderTemplate>
                    <ItemTemplate>
                        <tr id="trItem" class="SomeParentClass" runat="server">
                            <td>
                                <img id="imgToggleHomeInfo" runat="server" alt="show/hide repetitves" src="icon_plus.gif"
                                    style="cursor: pointer" />
                            </td>
                            <td>
                                <asp:Label ID="lbl" runat="server"></asp:Label>
                            </td>
                        </tr>
                        <tr id="trAddOnFee" runat="server" class="SomeClass" style="display: none;">
                            <td colspan="2">
                                <table cellpadding="4" cellspacing="2" width="100%">
                                    <tr>
                                        <td class="DgHeader">A</td>
                                        <td class="DgHeader">B</td>
                                    </tr>
                                    <asp:Repeater ID="repeatRepetitives" runat="server">
                                        <ItemTemplate>
                                            <tr>
                                                <td>
                                                    <asp:Label ID="lblA" runat="server"></asp:Label>
                                                </td>
                                                <td align="right"> 
                                                    <asp:Label ID="lblB" runat="server"></asp:Label>
                                                </td>
                                            </tr>
                                        </ItemTemplate>
                                    </asp:Repeater>
                                </table>
                            </td>
                        </tr>
                    </ItemTemplate>
                </asp:Repeater>
            </table>
```

How could I toggle the Rows with class as "SomeClass" inside on click of imgToggleHomeInfo" image on its parent row using Jquery?

Answer (score 1):

I'd find the parent row of the image then toggle it's next sibling.

```
$(document).ready( function() {
    $("[id$='imageToggleHomeInfo']").click( function() {
        $(this).closest('tr').next().toggle();
    });
})
```

Comment: $(this).parent('tr').next().toggle(); is not working. But this is working:
$(this).parent().parent().next().toggle();

Comment: Parent must be only searching the immediate parent.  The parent().parent() thing is ok, but you may be able to use the parents() method to look at all of the ancestors of the element.  This would depend on this table not being contained in another table.  If it is, you may need to use 'tr:last'.

Comment: +1 - if you can update this to use `.closest('tr')`, I realize it wasn't available at the time of the answer, but it would be useful for future googlers :)